# Create a self-signed certificate in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssl, ssl-certificate, tls1.2

I want to create a self-signed certificate in Python. I poked around a bit and found [some](https://www.linux.org/threads/creating-a-self-signed-certificate-with-python.9038/) places and other [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27164354/1111557) that basically say to import things from `OpenSSL`. I'm familiar with openssl's command line utilities so I figured that sounds like a good place to start. However, when I `import OpenSSL` I get `ImportError: No module named 'OpenSSL'`. When I tried `pip install --user OpenSSL` I got `No matching distribution found for OpenSSL`

I am using `python3` version `3.5` on one machine and `3.7` on another machine. It doesn't matter if it's *specifically* openssl, just as long as it's secure and well maintained and capable of generating valid certs for TLSv1.2 and preferably also TLSv1.3

I guess I *could* go run `os.system('openssl ...')` but I'd rather have it all in python or libraries instead of creating another process.

Answer (score 3):

The trouble was that I needed to install the `pyopenssl` library. `pip install --user pyopenssl` was needed rather than `pip install --user OpenSSL`. After that, `import OpenSSL` worked just fine.

It's rather frustrating that the library name and import name aren't the same!