# Export RSA Keys to stunnel.key

Tags: python-3.x, rsa, stunnel

I am trying to export some RSA Public and Private keys.
Just to clarify, I am NOT trying to sign the keys. I am trying to take the raw numbers for the keys and export them to `stunnel.key`. My code for generating RSA Keys:

```
from cryptographer import RSAKey
rsa = RSAKey()
keys = (rsa.pubkey, rsa.composite)
# Export keys to stunnel.key here
```

Comment: From a quick glance at [the docs](https://www.stunnel.org/howto.html) it sounds like stunnel just wants a certificate and key in standard PEM format. So you'll need to make a self-signed PEM certificate, presumably including the domain name of your stunnel proxy server in the certificate, and write it to a PEM file.

Comment: e.g. [this old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27164354/create-a-self-signed-x509-certificate-in-python)

Comment: I'm getting an error saying module 'OpenSSL.crypto' has no attribute 'TYPE_'

Comment: Sorry. I just had to delete the <wbr> code (I thought I deleted them all) Thank you